# How do I install debian package by Python script?

Tags: python, debian

I am trying to install Debian package file by Python script.So I used the script below.

```
import os
os.system('echo %(passwd)s | sudo dpkg -i 34.deb' %locals())
```

After run the Python script,the package was not installed.It shown the below message.

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

BUt when i try to install the package via terminall,It has been installed properly.The command which i gave in terminal is below.

```
sudo dpkg -i 34.deb
```

If you know,Let me.

Answer (score 2):

python too have the subprocess Module

```
import subprocess as sp
sp.call(["sudo","dpkg","-i", "some.deb"])
```

Must work

you can add each parameter

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Seems `sudo` doesn't accept password by pipe</strike>, so following the documentation

> Normally, if sudo requires a password, it will read it from the user's terminal.  If the -A (askpass) option is specified, a (possibly graphical) helper program is executed to read the user's password and output the password to the standard output.  If the SUDO_ASKPASS environment variable is set, it specifies the path to the helper program.
>                      Otherwise, if /etc/sudo.conf contains a line specifying the askpass program, that value will be used.  For example:
>
> ```
>                    # Path to askpass helper program
>                    Path askpass /usr/X11R6/bin/ssh-askpass
> ```
>
> If no askpass program is available, sudo will exit with an error.

you should pass with the `-A` flag an askpass program.

**EDIT:** seems that `sudo` accept password from `stdin`, use the `-S` flag.

Comment: Thank you,it works fine after sudo -S